# Import Customize PrimeNG module into an angular 2 project with webpack

Tags: angular, module, webpack, primeng

Currently I am using a a PrimeNG Module with my Angular 2 project. However I find some shortcoming in the PrimeNG Module functionality and decide to make some amendments on the PrimeNG module source code taken from their GitHub.

After customization, What could be the easy way to use the customized module in my project? I am using web pack for module loading.

Comment: Have you imported the PrimeNg module in your Angular module ?

Comment: Yes. That is working fine. But I want to know how to import the customize module?

Comment: update the post with the code. to help further. read the [**asking help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to revise your post

Comment: I do not have any specific code. I got the PrimeNG source code from GItHub and did some changes in a particular module. Now How can i import the changed module into my project?